# Disk mounts every second time and the following times no problem, but every first time I have an error "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock"

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a strange issue. When I switch my computer on after night or if it is idle all day long, it doesn't mount my HDD. I've got the error:

```
Aug 23 18:23:50 Big systemd[1]: Found device ST3250620AS VIDEO.
Aug 23 18:23:50 Big systemd[1]: Mounting /media/angbor/VIDEO...
Aug 23 18:23:50 Big systemd[1]: media-angbor-VIDEO.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Aug 23 18:23:50 Big systemd[1]: media-angbor-VIDEO.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 18:23:50 Big systemd[1]: Failed to mount /media/angbor/VIDEO.
Aug 23 18:23:50 Big systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
```

But after reboot, I have no problem mounting and using this HDD.

My fstab:

```
UUID=1a353931-8c00-4e5d-a137-16e1238d50bf /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=8fccc104-487a-498d-8e90-6cee6204afef /home ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=4b844b09-6459-4b0f-85b2-720f86f6fa94 /media/angbor/VIDEO ext4 defaults, realtime 0 0
```

My troublesome HDD is the last one.

lsblk -l:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
sda2   8:2    0 146,4G  0 part 
sda3   8:3    0 319,3G  0 part /home
sdb    8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk 
sdb1   8:17   0 232,9G  0 part 
sdc    8:32   0 232,9G  0 disk 
sdc1   8:33   0 232,9G  0 part /media/angbor/VIDEO
sdd    8:48   0 465,8G  0 disk 
sdd1   8:49   0 465,8G  0 part 
sde    8:64   0 149,1G  0 disk 
sde1   8:65   0   149G  0 part /
sr0   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1   11:1    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Here this guy

**sdc1   8:33   0 232,9G  0 part /media/angbor/VIDEO**

So... Any idea how to fix it?

Thanx

Comment: Do not exclude the possibility of a faulty drive - or something small like a faulty connection cable.

Comment: but this is too regular ... I expect in case of faulty connection more random behavior. But in my case only first switching on after long delay (about 5 - 8 hours), after reboot - every time everything is ok