# A problem with fstab and mounting hdds and permitions (I think)

Tags: fstab

I made a question few months ago about strange behavior of mounting process with fstab. Now I have a bit of new info, so I understand that the problem is with folders permission. But I can't catch this. So please help.
As root I created folders:

```
/mnt/doc
/mnt/video
```

In my fstab I wrote:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
/dev/sdc1 /mnt/doc ext4 defaults,realtime 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /mnt/video ext4 defaults,realtime 0 0
```

And after reboot I have this:

```
● mnt-doc.mount                           loaded failed failed  /mnt/doc                                     
● mnt-video.mount                         loaded failed failed  /mnt/video
```

Now, if I do this:

```
sudo mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/doc
sudo mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/doc
```

Both drives are mounted without any problem...

```
  mnt-doc.mount                           loaded active mounted /mnt/doc                                     
  mnt-video.mount                         loaded active mounted /mnt/video
```

So, I'm lost, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in your fstab-lines, I don't think that `realtime` is a valid mount option, use `relatime` which is a valid option.

You should not use device names like `/dev/sdxy` to define partitions in fstab. It's more reliable to use UUID or file-sytem labels although it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: yeah,sure.  before I've used UUID, it is just another attempt.
I'll try to correct  typo and will report a bit later
tanx

Comment: nope... Unfortunately the problem still there. 
● mnt-video.mount                         **loaded** failed failed  /mnt/video

My fstab:
UUID=692fa130-3906-4e93-bf28-b9f9829d81bb /mnt/doc ext4 defaults,relatime 0 0
UUID=4b844b09-6459-4b0f-85b2-720f86f6fa94 /mnt/video ext4 defaults,relatime 0 0

Have no idea where to dig

Comment: So.. I've ended up where I was before (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424787/disk-mounts-every-second-time-and-the-following-times-no-problem-but-every-firs) - HDD Video mounts only after reboot. If PC is off about 15 min and I run it, then I have my trouble only with HDD Video. HDD Doc mounts without problem. After reboot both are OK and are mounted. Sucks...

Comment: @DonBobskiy I don't know why, the fstab-lines look ok now, so there must be something else, maybe a faulty harddrive, but I'm not sure at all. Maybe you'd check the SMART status of that drive.

Comment: Hm... I'll check SMART
I'll be back :)